# PHP Check if string has consecutive underscores

Tags: php

How can I check if a string contains two or more consecutive underscore(_) characters, eg. `__` or `____` etc?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: This is a rudimentary regex/string match question, you really need to learn the basics before asking questions like these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('~__~', $string)){
    echo "has two or more underscores";
}
```

Comment: He means consecutive underscore.

Comment: The question is "two or more consecutive", not just 2 or more.

Comment: @genesis φ sorry, didn't refresh in time!

Comment: @CaNNaDaRk: I've got nice smilie there now :p

Answer (score 7):

if you want just to check, without performing any action, you can use [strpos](http://php.net/strpos)

```
if (strpos($string, '__') !== false)
```

However, if you want to replace them with single underscore for example, you need preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/_{2,}/', '_', $string);
```

here {2,} means 2 or more

Comment: PHP doesn't have strpost method. I think this is a typo error in your answer. Please correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strpos($string,"__")!==false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strpos($string, '__') !== FALSE;
```